# input/output lzw issue

Tags: c, lzw

Sup dudes,

I need your help on something. I'm writing a lzw compressor in C, and I'm having a spot o trouble with encode and decode. Here is what I have so far:

```
fixed it, thanks. 

$> ./encode < input.txt
code 1
code 2
code 3
code 4
code 1

$> ./decode < output.txt (this contains the codes, but as a stream of bits)
read 1
read 2
read 3
read 4
```

It appears to always skip the last code. When I GDB, I see that after C gets 258, it then gets EOF (-1), and I have no idea why the last code is skipped. Any tips?

Comment: I think we need to see the getInput(...) and putInput(...) function definitions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to completely understand your question, but here is my 2 cents.

try flushing out the stdout at the end

```
fflush(stdout);
```

This might help.